# sparse matrix implemented using vector of map

Tags: c++, matrix

As I wrote in another post (closed because I found some solution) I have implement a Sparse Matrix Class , the data container is done by a vactor of map where the index of vector rappresent the index of the row of the matrix for each index therefore the vector stored a map !

here the interface:

```
template <typename element_type>
class SparseMatrix {

  public:
   template<class T>
   friend SparseMatrix<T> operator+(const SparseMatrix<T>& m1 , const SparseMatrix<T>& m2 );  

   template<class T>
   friend SparseMatrix<T> operator-(const SparseMatrix<T>& m1 , const SparseMatrix<T>& m2 );  

   template <class T>
   friend SparseMatrix<T> operator*(const SparseMatrix<T>& m1 , const SparseMatrix<T>& m2  );

  public:
    // container type ;  
    using data_type = std::vector<std::map<std::size_t , element_type >> ;
    using it_rows   = typename std::map<std::size_t , element_type>::iterator ; 

    SparseMatrix(std::size_t rows , std::size_t cols) : rows{rows} , columns{cols}
    {
       data.resize(rows);     
    }

    SparseMatrix(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<element_type>> l );

    SparseMatrix(const std::string );  


    auto insert(std::size_t i , std::pair<std::size_t, element_type> p )
    { 
       assert( i <= rows && p.first <= columns); // , "Index out of bound" );
       data.at(i).insert(p);
    }

    auto insert(std::size_t i, std::size_t j, element_type val)
    {
      assert(i<=rows && j <=columns);
      data.at(i)[j] = val ;
    }

    auto identity() noexcept ;

    auto diag(const element_type& v) noexcept ;

    auto print() const noexcept ; 

    auto dataType() const noexcept ;

    auto traspose() noexcept ;

  private:

    std::size_t rows    ;
    std::size_t columns ;
      data_type data    ;     // vector containing row element 


};
```

In the previous post I asked about the traspose matrix .. I found this solution:

```
template <typename T>
auto SparseMatrix<T>::traspose() noexcept 
{

    //rows = columns ;   
    std::swap(rows,columns);  

    data_type newData ;
    newData.resize(rows);

    for(std::size_t i=0; i < columns ; i++)
    { 
      for(std::size_t j=0 ; j < rows ; j++)
      {
        if(data.at(i).find(j) != data.at(i).end())
        {
            newData.at(j)[i] = data.at(i).at(j) ;
        }    
      }
    }
    std::swap(data,newData);
}
```

Now i have no idea to how do compute the matrix product ... could you give me some advice ?

Ok .. thanks to suggeriment recived by @BeyelerStudios i got the poind and wrote the dot product in this way :

```
template <class T>
SparseMatrix<T> dot(const SparseMatrix<T>& m1 , const SparseMatrix<T>& m2  )
{
      if(m1.columns != m2.rows)
      {
            throw std::runtime_error("Matrix sizes dosent match the dot-product");
      }

      SparseMatrix<T> result{m1.rows  ,  m2.columns };

      for(std::size_t i=0 ; i < result.rows ; i++)
      {
           for(std::size_t j=0 ; j < result.columns ; j++ )
           {
                 for(std::size_t k=0; k< m1.columns ; k++)
                 {
                        if( m1.data.at(i).find(k) != m1.data.at(i).end() && 
                            m2.data.at(k).find(j) != m2.data.at(k).end()    )
                        {    
                            result.data.at(i)[j] += (m1.data.at(i).at(k) * m2.data.at(k).at(j)) ;
                        }
                 }
           }
      }
      return result ;      
}
```

now i open one other post for asking about determinant and inverse !

Comment: `A * B = C <-> Cij = Sum(Aik * Bkj)` skip every `Aik` and `Bkj` that is zero (not in the row-map), add `Cij` only if there were non-zero `Aik * Bkj`...

Comment: A matrix class can have a 2-dimentional data stored in `vector<vector<Type>> data;` but your class has 1-dimensional array, that seems to be complemented by `std::map` or something. Is there a reason for this complexity?

Comment: thanks @BeyelerStudios it is a very good point !!

Comment: @BarmakShemirani  the reson is that this is not an ordinary matrix ! here the most of the value of the matrix is 0 so .. I stored for each row a map in which the k is the column index and the value is the value contained in i,j index of matrix ! using vwctor of vector (or just a vector) I have to stored most big set of data .. using vector of map i stored only the non zero element :) sounds rasonable for you ? condider 100*100 matrix in which probably only 100 element is not zero ...